# Social Network development in node.js and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, architecture

I want to know following things so that I can fix my server architecture and make it more flexible.

1. Is it good to store home feed data [ex: Facebook homeFeed] to the variable for future manipulation or just fetch data related to homeFeed and manipulate everything which needs to be done on run time.

   Please note that data set of home feed can contain anything. [ not developed yet ]
2. Is there any limit to request to MongoDB at any given time which can create a delay in data processing?
3. Are node.js and MongoDB a good option for social network development?
4. If you know anything related to social network development then please share the pros and cons.

Comment: Please read [ask] and the other material in the [help]; this question is far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good to store home feed data [ex: Facebook homeFeed] to the variable for future manipulation or just fetch data related to homeFeed and manipulate everything which needs to be done on run time.

You can (and sometimes should) pre-compute home feed data for certain users (for example those who are the most active). You don't store that in a *variable* though, you *cache* the results with something like [Redis](https://redis.io/).

Generating the home feed on a "request" basis is also possible and good.

Both approaches require careful thinking about your system's architecture, performance, scalability, robustness, fault-tolerance, etc...

> Is there any limit to request to MongoDB at any given time. which can create a delay in data processing?

Yes. A MongoDB instance (or any other database) has limited resources.  Look at the [Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) and [Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) docs of MongoDB for more info about how to work with MongoDb at scale.

> Are node.js and MongoDB are a good option for social network development.

Node.js and MongoDb are a good combinations for quick prototyping, you can get productive fairly quickly. Any language(s) you are familiair with is/are a good choice here, since your focus seems to be on architecture. Go, Java and PHP are good candidates too.

In the real world social networks are built with a lot more tools than that. Since the teams use various programming languages, databases and frameworks depending on the task at hand.

Comment: Can u share some tips and tricks which I should learn and care while developing it as for real-world application

Comment: Look into scalable systems architecture. It's a really huge (and fascinating) subject, there's no _tips and tricks_ to it to be honest

Comment: scalable systems architecture that's a tip for me :p and highly appreciate your answer and passion for this field -- architecture.